# Model and Control of a Physical System

Tags: control, control-system, physics, modeling, model

Suppose i have a physical system (set of interacting elements  ) that i want to control.

Best thing we can do to understand this physical system and hence control it, is to model it.
We end-up then with mathematical equations ( probabily differential equations ) which we can transform into transfer-function or state-space, for example.

In these mathematical equations, there are some variables that can be controlled by the user, by nature, and some that can't be controlled directly.
Those that can be controlled we can call the possible inputs.

My question is, what is it that makes some variables of a system be possibly controlled and others not ? If they are all behaving equally in mathematical equations, what differentiates them regarding this controlability ?

E.g. Suppose we have the simple physical system : An object with mass m.

We model it by f=ma  and then we have 4 possible variables,  f,a,v and position.

While they are all coupled, by common sense, it seems like the only possible variable that i can exert direct control on is force.   Why is this so ?   Why couldn't i choose a to be the input and let f be the controlled variable ?    What dictates that f is the only possible variable i can manipulate ( the input ) ?
The mathematical equations and the physics don't tell us that. Some mind from other universe could come and whenever seeing this model f=ma of a physical object containing these variables "a" and "f" would have all the right to think that he could choose to manipulate either the acceleration directly or the force directly, withouth knowing that he could only possible manipulate the force directly.
  What would inform him that, is really only experience ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: For some systems you can control mass, for example a submarine ballast tank as long as you consider the water inside to be part of its mass. But I don't have any rigorous explanation other than as you say experience of what's possible / practical within a given system.

Comment: There is no law that you can control only certain variables. You can for instance control a using a centrifuge. But does this have anything to do with electrical engineering??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: @LeonHeller This question is about control systems which is often apart of any engineering eduction, but specifically in electrical engineering.

Answer (score 1):

The ultimate controlling factor is your imagination and the application of known laws of physics in our universe here on the Newtonian macro-surface of Earth. Once you get into outer space you enter Einstein thinking of special relativity which throws Newton out the window. Then going into the micro-world of inside the atom of quantum mechanics it throws out Einstein's Special Theory of relativity out the window. If String theory is proven it will throw out quantum mechanics out the window. There are forces in nature that are still not known what they really are, but can be easily measured, predicted and even used to our advantage such as electricity, light, heat, gravity and electro-magnetic radiation. No one knows what exactly they are as we can not build a microscope smaller than needed to observe these phenomena, so be conscious that what you can directly influence causes an indirect influence on abstract thoughts such as acceleration or heat, as one example away from your question. So in essence be content with what you can directly influence and knowledgeable of what you are indirectly responsible for. Numbers are only human creation to be used as a crutch to try to understand the incomprehensible. The more I know, the more I realize how much I don't know. An answer in brief would be to learn and know the laws of physics as they are not just good ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you got so many down votes, other than perhaps you are asking a general question rather than a specific electronics problem and your understanding of physics is a little confused.

Force comes in many forms in physics because mass can be accelerated in many different ways. In addition to the way this is applied (like electrical fields, graviational fields, etc.) force can also be applied lineally, non-linearly, time-variant, etc.  In your equation F=ma.  There are 3 variables (and a hidden one, time) and multiple dimensions.  So there are many parameters that contribute to a system's complexity.

Unstable systems can be stabilized by finding a method to keep the system operating in a quasi-stable state.  Finding the method is usually difficult.

To approach this problem you have to first understand basic [control theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_theory) for simple systems with simple feedback:

[image: feedback]

Then move on to [Non-linear Control Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_control).  Robotics, plasma physics and others benefit greatly from non-linear control analysis.

Both of these topics are very well documented and there are many sources of information about them on the internet.